# AWS Api Gateway: get #hash (fragment identifier)

Tags: aws-api-gateway

For example such GET:
https://XXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com#my_hash=XXX

I did not found any way to get `my_hash`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New knowledge every day - as it turned out by HTTP - the web browser do not send hash portion to the server.